# Ranger Run Custom .bash_profile Command

Tags: git, ranger

Suppose I have the following in my ~/.bash_profile file:

```
function lazygit() {
    git add .
    git commit -a -m "$1"
    git push
}
```

I have run source .bash_profile and it works well in terminal on my Mac.

However, when I run the command in Ranger I receive the following prompt:

```
/bin/bash: lazygit: command not found
```

How do I fix this error?

Comment: I used `S` and entered `bash-3.2$ lazygit "test push"` and received `bash: lazygit: command not found`

Answer (score 2):

@Christopher mentioned the rc.conf file.

https://github.com/ranger/ranger/blob/master/ranger/config/rc.conf

Naturally, you can map commands in the config file and call them in Ranger:

```
% navigate to the rc.conf file
cd ~
cd ./.config
cd ./ranger
vim rc.conf % you may need to make this file

% add the following into the file and save with :wq
map gp shell -w read -p "Enter commit msg: " msg && git add -A && git commit -m "$msg" && git push -u origin master

map gc shell -w read -p "Enter org: " org && read -p "Enter repo: " repo && git clone http://YOURREPOADDRESSHERE/$org/$repo
```

In Ranger, you can now push with "gp" and clone with "gc".

For further reading also see: https://superuser.com/questions/1048647/how-to-define-new-commands-in-the-ranger-file-manager